# Qt: Capturing images continuously from camera fills the memory

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qpixmap, qcamera

I am trying to capture images continuously so I can send them using UDP. I am doing this to implement a live video streaming program.

The code below captures images continuously and assigns images to QGraphicsScene so I can test if images play like a video. But when I run the program my computer freezes after couple seconds even though I delete the pointers. How can I fix this problem ?

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QThread>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
ui->setupUi(this);
scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);
cam = new QCamera;
cam->setCaptureMode(QCamera::CaptureStillImage);

viewfinder = new QCameraViewfinder;
viewfinder->show();
QCameraImageCapture *cap = new QCameraImageCapture(cam);
cap->setCaptureDestination(QCameraImageCapture::CaptureToBuffer);

cam->setViewfinder(viewfinder);


QObject::connect(cap, &QCameraImageCapture::imageCaptured, [=] (int id, QImage img) {

     while(true){
        QByteArray *buf = new QByteArray;
        QBuffer *buffer=new QBuffer(buf);
        buffer->open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
        img.save(buffer, "BMP");
        QPixmap *pixmap = new QPixmap();
        pixmap->loadFromData(buffer->buffer());
        scene->addPixmap(*pixmap);
        delete buf;
        delete buffer;
        delete pixmap;

        QThread::sleep(0.0416);
        cap->capture();

     }

});

QObject::connect(cap, &QCameraImageCapture::readyForCaptureChanged, [=] (bool state) {
   if(state == true) {
       cam->searchAndLock();
       cap->capture();
       cam->unlock();
   }
});
cam->start();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Comment: Please tell me why you downvote my question. I am new on this website but with your help I can edit my question accordingly.

Comment: Do not worry about downvotes, worry about your question, if you think your question is the best you could post then leave it there, if instead you think it may be better then work on it. The votes are and should be anonymous in SO, so do not ask for explanations, that is considered noise.

Comment: I would recommend you read [ask] and improve your question, currently it is a [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) because your goal is to *write image to buffer and send it via sockets* but you ask for a possible solution: *But when I run the program my computer freezes after couple seconds even though I delete the pointers* that you do not have certainty that it is the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

You should use imageAvailable() instead of imageCaptured signal.

Here is an example :

```
connect(cap, &QCameraImageCapture::imageAvailable, [=] (int id, QVideoFrame v ) {

    if (v.isValid()) {
        if(v.map(QAbstractVideoBuffer::ReadOnly)) {

            QByteArray bitsVideo( (char *) v.bits(), v.mappedBytes() );

            //call to your send raw data function (over UDP) : 
            //datagram will contain frame details e.g : [ width, hight, byteperline, format, rawdata ]

            sendDataOverUDP( v.width(), v.height(), 
                             v.bytesperLine(), 
                             QVideoFrame::imageFormatFromPixelFormat(v.pixelFormat()), 
                             bitsVideo );


        }
    }
});
```

The others side, the server or other clients will create the image from raw data received as follows:

```
    void onDataImageReceived( int width, int height, 
                          int bytePerLine, 
                          QImage::Format fmt, 
                          QByteArray bitsVideo )
{

    QImage img ((uchar *)bitsVideo.data(), width, height, bytesPerLine, fmt);
    //do something with img ...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with `QCamera` and related classes but the `lambda` you connect the `QCameraImageCapture::imageCaptured` signal to doesn't look correct.  That signal is emitted when a single frame is ready for preview.  In your `lambda`, however, you have...

```
while(true){
    QByteArray *buf = new QByteArray;
    QBuffer *buffer=new QBuffer(buf);
    buffer->open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    img.save(buffer, "BMP");
    QPixmap *pixmap = new QPixmap();
    pixmap->loadFromData(buffer->buffer());
    scene->addPixmap(*pixmap);
    delete buf;
    delete buffer;
    delete pixmap;

    QThread::sleep(0.0416);
    cap->capture();
}
```

That `while` loop never exits and will block the `Qt` event processing loop.  Note, also, that the code chunk...

```
QByteArray *buf = new QByteArray;
QBuffer *buffer=new QBuffer(buf);
buffer->open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
img.save(buffer, "BMP");
QPixmap *pixmap = new QPixmap();
pixmap->loadFromData(buffer->buffer());
scene->addPixmap(*pixmap);
delete buf;
delete buffer;
delete pixmap;
```

is overkill and (unless I'm mistaken) basically amounts to...

```
scene->addPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(img));
```

So I think your `lambda` should be more like (untested)...

```
[=](int id, QImage img)
{
    scene->addPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(img));
}
```

Comment: Like I stated in my question all those lines of codes are for testing purposes. I am not just trying to  show image on QGraphicsScene, I am trying to read/write image on buffer so afterwards I can read/write those buffers to socket to implement UDP streaming program. I can't use `scene->addPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(img));`  on server side since it doesn't have the image. So sadly your answer here not helping me. Sorry for my poor English.

Comment: The main point in my answer was to get rid of the `while (true) { ... }` loop in your `lambda` -- it's blocking the `Qt` event loop making your program unresponsive.

Comment: Thanks but with your code I will not be able to write image to buffer and send it via sockets.

Comment: @onurcevik As @G.M. mentioned, he was trying to show you that the `while` loop never exits, which is the reason your application freezes

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation of your goal to "... capture images continuously to send them ..."
via the slow QCameraImageCapture in a loop calls for trouble (lagging, UI blocking).

Better use the following subclass.

```
// subclass from QAbstractVideoSurface
class AltVideoSurface: public QAbstractVideoSurface{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    AltVideoSurface(QObject * parentLabel=NULL) : QAbstractVideoSurface(parentLabel)
    {
        this->parentLabel = (QLabel*)parentLabel;
    }

    QLabel * parentLabel;

    QList<QVideoFrame::PixelFormat> supportedPixelFormats(QAbstractVideoBuffer::HandleType type) const {
        return QList<QVideoFrame::PixelFormat>() << QVideoFrame::Format_RGB24;
    }

    // will called on every new video frame
    bool present(const QVideoFrame& frame)
    {
        if ( frame.isValid() ) {
        
            // clone frame
            QVideoFrame cloneFrame(frame);
            // map frame's memory from video to cpu
            cloneFrame.map(QAbstractVideoBuffer::ReadOnly);
            
            // have a full resolution image
            QImage imageFull(cloneFrame.bits(),
                             cloneFrame.width(),
                             cloneFrame.height(),
                             QVideoFrame::imageFormatFromPixelFormat(cloneFrame.pixelFormat()));
                             
            // release cpu mapping
            cloneFrame.unmap();
        
            // perhaps make an additional scaled image
            QImage imageSmall = imageFull.scaled( 640, 480, Qt::KeepAspectRatio);
            // render small image in UI viewlinder (here a QLabel)
            parentLabel->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(imageSmall));
        
            return true;
        } 
        
        return false;
    }
};


mainwindow h-file
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
...
    QScopedPointer<QCamera> m_camera;
    AltVideoSurface*        m_surface;
...
    
    
mainwindow cpp-file 
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Call the subclassed QAbstractVideoSurface within your camera init method.
...

    // init camera
    m_camera.reset(new QCamera(QCameraInfo::defaultCamera()));

    // set video mode
    m_camera->setCaptureMode(QCamera::CaptureVideo);
    
    // the subclassed QAbstractVideoSurface as view (here a QLabel) gets full resolution images
    m_surface = new AltVideoSurface(ui->labelView);
    
    // connect camera, viewfinder and subclassed surface
    m_camera->setViewfinder(m_surface);
    
...
```